# TreeSet definition of an iterator is not consistent with the interface Iterator?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, treeset

I am using some legacy code which uses `TreeSet` to perform the sort of a collection of objects. (**alternatives to using TreeSet are a good reference, but I am not looking to change that in particular**).

The class has two methods `iterator()`

> iterator()
>
> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set in ascending order.

and `descendingIterator()`

> descendingIterator()
>
> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set in descending order.

My concept of the `Iterator` interface implemented by a `Collection` or in own implementation, is that **you can not assume any specific ordering**.

In the implementation already provided it is assumed that the two calls give an iterator in correct ordering. The results are good for now, my fear is that it is a false assumption and since it violates the `Iterator` interface principles, it could change in the future.

I do not have experience with `TreeSet` and I do not see *traversal* methods to poll the elements in order. Is there a way to do this or just stick with the `Iterator`'s and hope for the best?

**EDIT**

Example usage:

```
TreeSet<BeatDesc> beatsOrderedTS = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<BeatDesc>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(BeatDesc lhs, BeatDesc rhs) {
        return lhs.getTS() - rhs.getTS() < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
BeatDesc latest = beatsOrderedTS.descendingIterator().next()
```

**EDIT**

```
{//block 1
    Iterator<BeatDesc> itBeatDesc = beatsOrderedTS.descendingIterator();
}
{//block 2
   for (BeatDesc beatDesc : itBeatDesc){
        ....
}
```

So by using this format you create a binding between *block 1* and *block 2*

Comment: You don't need to hope. The specification of TreeSet.iterator() guarantees that it iterates in ascending order. It's true, and will always be true.

Comment: `TreeSet` is a sorted set ( unique elements ). Sorting is the only order guaranteed. Your code shouldn't assume anything else. What else ordering you talk about when you say , **correct ordering**?

Comment: In order for `TreeSet` to be a `Collection`, it only has to implement the methods defined in the `Collection` interface.  There is nothing wrong with it adding extra functionality.  You might also want to look into `LinkedHashMap` which is another ordered collection.

Comment: @Radu Ionescu great explanation of the problem.. with some lines of code would be even better :)

Comment: @Sabir If you obtain the iterator by doing a deep first or breadth first search starting from the root you get different iterators. The implementation might be this, but from my knowledge of the concept of iterator is not to assume ordering, like when you write `for (Elem element : elements)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea that "**you can not assume any specific ordering**" of the elements returned by an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). The javadoc just says:

> An iterator over a collection.

It doesn't say anything about ordering.

Now, the javadoc of the [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) method of `Collection` says:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection. There are no guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned (**unless this collection is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee**).

For example, [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), and all [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations *do* guarantee a defined order:

- `TreeSet` - The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
- `LinkedHashSet` - This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).
- `EnumSet` - The iterator returned by the iterator method traverses the elements in their natural order (the order in which the enum constants are declared).
- `List` - An ordered collection (also known as a *sequence*). - `iterator()` returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.

Comment: How can you tell  _this collection is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee_ other than logic or assumptions? I am not arguing that it is not correct, but how can you get the **guarantee** in a consistent way other than going in the code of each collection?

Comment: @RaduIonescu The guarantee is in the "contract" as defined by the documentation, just as I listed above, e.g. `TreeSet` *explicitly* states the order (natural or by `Comparator`).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is meant to maintain the order (either ascending or descending) of the elements as per either :

- The Object that you are going to insert into the set implement's `Comparable` something like:

  ```
   class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {..
  ```
- while constructing `TreeSet` where you pass your implementation of how you want to order elements within set by implementing `Comparator` interface something like:

  ```
   class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {..
   ... new TreeSet<>(new MyComparator());
  ```

Hence it is guaranteed you would get the elements in order as per your implementation of those interfaces.

Comment: I understand how the structure is constructed and mantained, but this does not mean I could not store a linkedlist of the object references as they arrive and output the iterator of this linkedlist, or maybe have a hashmap for fast access and return the iterator of that.